# Using System.Web.Routing in a console application

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to use the routing infrastructure in a console application. Ideally reusing the router provided in .NET 4.5 with a custom Hanlder ( and not a IHttpHandler ( this is a console app so no HttpContext available). The main idea is to react to event and dispatch the event/message to the correct handler. It looks to me very close to MVC and would like to "inspire" me with this framework. Has anyone already used the Router in this context ?

Comment: Is there any other framework (Rx, ... ) that you would suggest to achieve this.